# How do you save the "Level" in Arena Chess?

Tags: software, pgn

Is it possible to save the "Level" in [Arena Chess](http://www.playwitharena.com/) PGN files? Whenever I save a game as a .PGN file, and the level is set as "Time Per Move", Arena opens the game and sets the level to "Blitz" automatically. This only happens when I set the game level to "Time per Move". Any other levels like Tournament, the game when opened will stay Tournament.